# Wordpress - Open Thickbox window in customize.php screen

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin that creates a type of widged that does allow me to open a thickbox in both in dashboard and in the frontend of wordpress. What I want is to open this thickbox in the customize.php edtior, the one that appears in the frontend admin bar when you have the proper rights to use it ( like when you are an admin). I have a button and when I click it, it opens the thickbox window but this doesen't work in the custimize.php editor. Why I cand do this right now and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The thickbox has an incorrect z-index.

Solution:

Add this to your .css file:

```
#TB_window {
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
 }
```